# string with the data of the static file not writing into the temporary file c++

Tags: c++, file-io

Some days ago I watched a computerphile video about grep and thought, 'why don't make my own version of it in c++?'.
So I began writing the code, but I encountered the problem at the very beginning of the program, when all the data in the stored file ( in my case txt ) have to  be copied in the temporary file ( the one you work with ), of my string variable not writing into the temporary file, although the data of the stored file are succesfully put in the string.
I tried changing more then once how the string is written in the temporary file ( using classic << command, using write, using fputs and using fputc ), but none of these works.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
```

`#pragma warning(suppress : 4996) //disable compiler error for use of deprecated function ( std::tmpnam )`

```
std::fstream temp_file ( std::tmpnam(NULL) ); //creates temporay file

void tmp_init(std::fstream& static_file) { 
//copy all the contents of static_file into temporary file
    std::string line; //support string for writing into temporary file
    std::cout << "copying\n";
    while (std::getline(static_file, line)) 
    //writes into the support string until file is ended
        temp_file << line; //writes into temporary file with string
    std::cin.ignore(); //clears input buffer
 }

void output() { //output of temporary file
    std::cout << "Output:\n";
    std::string output_line; 
    //support string for output write the    output
    while ( std::getline(temp_file, output_line)) 
   //copies line to line from the temporary file in the support string
        std::cout << output_line; //output of support string
    std::cin.ignore();//clears input buffer
}


int main() {
    std::fstream my_file; //creates static file
    my_file.open("file.txt"); //open the file
    if (my_file.is_open()) std::cout << "Open\n"; 
    //Check if file is opened correctely
    tmp_init(my_file); 
    //copy all contents of the static file in the temporary_file
    output(); //output of temporary file
    std::cin.get();
}
```

Any suggestion?

EDIT:

I found a parallel solution for this, not creating a temporary file using std::tmpnan (NULL) but creating a file with filename (~ + static file filename ) and then deleting it from the hard drive with std::remove ( temporary file filename ).
Before using std::remove() remember to call the method close() on the temporary file or is not going to remove it ( this is because the file is created when you call close on it, and by not doing it remove won't find the file and thus won't remove it).
The code:

```
class file : public std::fstream {
public:
std::string path;
    file(std::string&& file_path) {
        path = file_path;
        std::fstream::open(path, std::ios::out);
    }
};

int main() {
    file static_file("file.txt");
    file temp_file('~' + static_file.path);
    static_file.close();
    temp_file.close();
    std::remove(temp_file.path.c_str() );
}
```

Comment: Did you mean "cat" instead of "grep"? I think you're saying you wrote to a file, then you tried to read what you wrote but it didn't work. If so, that's because your handle has a position within the file. Look for "tell" and "seek" methods (or possibly seekp/seekg). You probably want to write, flush, seek(0), read. Or better, open for writing, write, close, open for reading, read, close.

Comment: oh man, you saved my day! big up for you, I thought that there was no problem in lefting the file open.